# Forcing radiobutton to use the diamond as the indicator, Tcl/Tk 8.6

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

In the process of porting an application from Tcl/Tk 8.4 to 8.6.  For historic reasons, we desire to keep the radio button indicators to have the shape of a diamond.  From [the 8.6 docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm#M19), it appears that this should be possible:

```
A radiobutton is a widget that displays a textual string, bitmap or image and a diamond 
or circle called an indicator.
```

However, I'm unable to figure out how to get the radio button to use the diamond.

One possibility is to use `ttk::radiobutton` instead, however, it's not a drop-in replacement.  The `ttk::radiobutton` does not recognize the `-anchor` option, which we currently use.

Answer (score 1):

The indicator shape depends on the platform; the exact rendering is usually done in a way that approximately follows the host platform's style guidelines (as they stood at the time that the code was written, alas). Indicator shape isn't exposed as a controllable feature to the Tk API, as the control of how it is done is via which rendering code is compiled at the C level. Changing that is really messy, and you really ought to ask yourselves whether you're really needing that old Motif look (that was where those diamonds came from).

The Ttk widgets *with the right theme* do much better (the `classic` theme has the diamond), but move some of their layout functionality into the style system precisely because things like anchoring are often specified by platform style guides. We can override… but the documentation for Ttk is very poor. However, the [tkdocs style tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) is a lot better. In particular, we can use it to see that we can make a *derived style* that will apply the extra options that you want and that you can apply where you want.

```
# Switch to classic style
ttk::style theme use classic

# Make the style. Derived because of the . and the existing style name
ttk::style configure RightAnchor.TRadiobutton -anchor e

# Make some widgets that use the style
ttk::radiobutton .example1 -variable foo -value foo -text "This is an example" \
    -style RightAnchor.TRadiobutton
ttk::radiobutton .example2 -variable foo -value bar -text "This is also an example" \
    -style RightAnchor.TRadiobutton
# This one doesn't use the style, for comparison
ttk::radiobutton .example3 -variable foo -value boo -text "This is not an example"
pack .example1 .example2 .example3 -fill x
```

I'm not certain that this is going to work for you — Ttk is *intensely* complicated and has a lot of features where it simply doesn't provide as much feedback as I'd like — but it is the best idea I've got. If this doesn't work, your main option would be to make a megawidget (probably using a canvas) that does what you really want, but that's a lot of work.

---

Are your diamonds ***really*** necessary? Normal user expectations of radiobuttons on different platforms may not expect them any more.

Comment: The old motif look would help for the case of high DPI display. Currently, Tk radiobuttons and checkbuttons look tiny on them.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  Question about the `ttk` - are they supposed to be a drop-in replacement?  see my issue with the lack of support for the `-anchor` option for `radiobutton`.  I may not need it, but I need to see if any other options are not supported that we might be using.  But, if it's not intended to be a drop-in replacement, the point is kind of moot.  We have some 1800 uses of `radiobutton` in our code.  Trying to weigh the costs/benefits of various solutions - and just using the new look is one option.

Note: the diamond scaled nicely with font sizes, the new circles do NOT.